# IIF and CDate getting #error in SSRS expression?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I've got data from a db in Reporting Services, which contains the datetime as a integer like this: 20160511, but in some case it is just a 0. I need an expression to do the following: if the value is 0, put the string "never", else put the data in correct format. 
I've tried to use an expression in SSRS report, something like this:

```
==IIF(Fields!name.Value=0,"never", Cdate(...))
```

If the data is correct, working fine, and shows the date, but in the fields, where 0, i'm getting this error: #error and some warnings.

If i just use this:

```
==IIF(Fields!name.Value=0,"never", "something else")
```

Here is working the true branch, it shows the never and the something else string correctly. I've tried the first code wth Is nothing date, and others, but it didn't worked.

I'm really confusing. Has anybody any idea for fix the first code?

Comment: What's the data type for the column? I wonder if the `#Error` value stems from outputting the `string` "never" into a `DateTime` column.

Comment: in the database it's integer, but in the second case, they write the strings without problems and warnings, so i dont think thats the problem.

Comment: =IIF evaluates both the left and right side of the if statement, it is likely the right side can not be evaluated when the Field!name.Value = 0. 
You can use =IF in this case which should fix the immediate problem however you reporting server has to be 2008 or later i believe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert date into varchar format and your formula will work as expected. You can use **Format** **function** for the same. For e.g. if you want output in mm/dd/yyyy then your Expression will look something like below,

```
==IIF(Fields!name.Value=0,"never", Format(Fields!Date.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put another IIF inside the CDATE to get rid of the error:

```
=IIF(Fields!name.Value = 0,"never", Cdate(IIF(Fields!name.Value=0, "2000-01-01", Fields!Date.Value)) )
```